# Disable li with ul

Tags: jquery, parent, superfish

I'm trying to disable the parent link with child links to it using jQuery.  Can anyone help me???

I want to still keep the child links active.  Below is the jQuery that I'm using.  I'm using the superfish menu, which I'm sure is pretty common.  Any help will do!

Thank you in advance!

I'm sorry, but I'm new to this.  I wasn't sure where to start.  What I want to do is disable the "Tutorials" link below, but keep my Photoshop, Illustrator, and Web Design links active.  I know you can just add a link to "Tutorials" and it won't be active, but is there a way to do that in jQuery?  Thanks!

- Home
- Tutorials

  - Photoshop
  - Illustrator
  - Web Design
- Articles

  - Web Design
  - User Experience
- Inspiration

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but aren't the events on the LINKS (A-tags), not the list items (LI)?

Comment: Do we need all of this code for your problem? Can you trim it down to what is relevant?

Comment: Could you describe your issue in a little more detail, and a little more focus? This is a bit “Here’s a bunch of code, fix it for me”, which is not what Stack Overflow is for. I don’t understand your description of what you’re trying to achieve, and I’m not clear which bit of your code to expect to achieve it, or what’s not working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to this.  I wasn't sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your HTML is along the lines of...

(I added some classes for purposes of my answer)

```
<ul class="list">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="tutorials">
      <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Articles</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
</ul>
```

You will need some type of identifier to tell jQuery to target the 'Tutorials' link. I told my statement to look at the unordered list named 'list', then any elements with the class 'tutorials' and finally the anchor that is a direct child of the preceding element 'tutorials'.

```
$(function() {
   $('.list .tutorials > a').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
   });
});
```

You can refer to here for more information on th preventDefault method and the return: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

You will be able to keep the anchor wrapped around 'Tutorials' without losing your styling or click cursor. This is just one example of how you could attack this.